# Using content field widget in custom block?

Tags: blocks, media, entities

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to implement a content field type (image_field) with a widget (imagefield_crop) on a custom block.

The block currently has an upload image feature, but I want to implement the imagefield_crop widget when uploading the image in the block.

I have tried Beans(resets all current blocks), CCK Blocks (only implements one field type(need Date, Image, Body)), and some other modules. It would be easier to insert some code in my block.module, but I get negative results.

I am getting close to implementing the "function imagefield_crop_field_widget_form" into my code, but cannot reference the module nor get any positive responses.

The image type for the module is a 'managed_file'.

btw, I have been using Drupal for ~20 days and have not hit any major road blocks till now. (Pun intended?). I know that blocks are not entities and cannot contain field content types, not to mention Drupal 8 will implement blocks as entities(I can't wait that long). Thanks in advanced!